# Creating reliable snapshots of Linux system

Tags: boot, backup

I've used preinstalled Backups program as well as Timeshift.
According to this https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timeshift.html article Timeshift makes a snapshot of the whole system and allows
for recovery if anything goes wrong.

It has happened to be before that my laptop failed to boot after installing latest updates.
How do I use the snapshots in case of boot failure ? Is there some recovery menu
I can use to restore my system from the snapshot created by Timeshift ?

Answer (score 1):

To recover a non-booting system which has a Timeshift snapshot on it from before the problem ocurred,

> If the main system is not bootable, then it is possible to boot from an Ubuntu Live CD, install Timeshift on the live system, and restore a snapshot on the main system.

Source: https://teejeetech.com/timeshift/

(I have not done this myself, but I did recently use Timeshift to recover from a similarly awkward situation and it worked)

Comment: I've tested it myself today. I proceed as you described and after the snapshot was restored I rebooted and laptop failed to boot.  :(